# A searchable database with support for tagging words

Tags: information-management

I'm looking for something fairly specific. Basically it would take the form of an organization program such as exists for files (e.g., [Pixa](http://www.pixa-app.com/)), where you can group files, tag them, and search for them. But I don't want to organize files; I want to organize words.

The words need to be organizable within subcategories. The subcategories need to be taggable. The words themselves need to be taggable.

I need to be able to search this database of grouped words by multiple parameters: character length, word contains, group tag, word tag, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [Word Database](https://simitless.com/en/templates?or=st&preview=templates-words-database) template on Simitless. Although the template gives you a basic idea of what your database can look like, you can always:

- add/remove/change the names of the columns, depending on what parameters you want to track. The way it works is that you get predefined spreadsheet-columns-like fields that you can select from to track/collect only the data you need,
- import and export your data at any time,
- tag your words and word categories,
- search your words by any parameter. Once your app is created, simply go to your app directly (use the URL that is assigned to your app when you build it), click the "+" next to "Filter by", select what to search to then see instant results.

Here is a little screenshot what it looks like with some "dummy data" I input into the template:

[image: http://www.clipular.com/c/4864052814938112.png?k=NN6t1CCjUp3yY8dKJBDhDPIQ0JI]

**Full disclosure: I am part of the startup that designed that platform.** We just launched recently, still in beta. If you want to try it out and need some help, I can definitely give you a hand.