# Easy GUI database for organising things by tags

Tags: windows, database, gui, information-management

I am searching for Windows software, to organise words/text by tags.

When you select a tag, you can view all the items connected with this tag. Also, an item can be assigned to many tags. I am not experienced with databases, and also, simple users will use it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is this a standalone single-user app, or a shared multi-user app? A native desktop app or s web app?

Comment: For a single user only, both native and web preffered.

Comment: Your question looks similar to another one [here](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/28050/a-searchable-database-with-support-for-tagging-words). I suggested an answer, maybe it can work for you too. Let me know if you try it.